# sheidim, servant of satan, death on sight, duck feet?

Tags: death, myths, sheidim-demons

Are sheidim servants of satan? Will you really die if you see it's true form? And do they really have chicken feet?

Answer (score 5):

**No.**   The Gemara and Medrash are full of references of people seeing them and surviving to tell of it.

For example, according to the Gemara (Gitin chap. 7), the way Shlomo Hamelech realized it was Ashmdai the King of Sheidim versus the actual king was by this indicator of birds feet (maybe calves feet), and concluded that the homeless man was the real king.

Comment: +1 This answer could use better explanation and formatting, though.

Comment: This is not a Medrash, it is a Gemara in Gitin Perek 7.

Answer (score 1):

1) No. 2) No, but there was a story of a guy who did trick and saw the supernatural world and then died, until the rabbis prayed around his bed and he was revived. 3) Yes.

Comment: ................What?

Comment: @HodofHod he asked 3 questions

Comment: I know, that's not my question. My question is on #2 which is hard to understand. Also, a source for any/all of your points would be nice.

Comment: @HodofHod The gemara (B'rachos 6a) says that R' Bibi bar Abaye used the method described there to see mazikin, and he was harmed as a result (it doesn't say he died). The rabbis prayed for him and he recovered.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding question 2 and 3:

> תניא אבא בנימין אומר אלמלי נתנה רשות לעין לראות אין כל בריה יכולה לעמוד מפני המזיקין
>
> האי מאן דבעי למידע להו לייתי קיטמא נהילא ונהדר אפורייה ובצפרא חזי כי כרעי דתרנגולא האי מאן דבעי למחזינהו ליתי שלייתא דשונרתא אוכמתא בת אוכמתא בוכרתא בת בוכרתא ולקליה בנורא ולשחקיה ולימלי עיניה מניה וחזי להו ולשדייה בגובתא דפרזלא ולחתמי' בגושפנקא דפרזלא דילמא גנבי מניה ולחתום פומיה כי היכי דלא ליתזק רב ביבי בר אביי עבד הכי חזא ואתזק בעו רבנן רחמי עליה ואתסי
>
> In another baraita it was taught that Abba Binyamin says: If the eye was given permission to see, no creature would be able to withstand the abundance and ubiquity of the demons and continue to live unaffected by them.
>
> One who seeks to know that the demons exist should place fine ashes around his bed, and in the morning the demons’ footprints appear like chickens’ footprints, in the ash. One who seeks to see them should take the afterbirth of a firstborn female black cat, born to a firstborn female black cat, burn it in the fire, grind it and place it in his eyes, and he will see them. He must then place the ashes in an iron tube sealed with an iron seal [gushpanka] lest the demons steal it from him, and then seal the opening so he will not be harmed. Rav Beivai bar Abaye performed this procedure, saw the demons, and was harmed. The Sages prayed for mercy on his behalf and he was healed.

Source: http://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.6a.6?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en